# Custom page showing 500 error in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I have created a custom page when clicking on a button this page should be displayed, but its showing **HTTP ERROR 500**.

Here is the xml file in `frontend/layout/rma_customer_createrequest.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
      <block class="Company\Vendor\Block\Customer\ListReturns" name="customer.rma.create.request" template="Company_Vendor::customer/rma/createrequest.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Accordingly I have created a controller `Company/Vendor/Controller/Customer/CreateRequest`

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('New Manage Page'));
   return $resultPage;
 }
```

Comment: have your returned the $resultPage object in execute method ?  -> return $resultPage;

Comment: Yes! 
 public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('New Manage Page'));
        
        return $resultPage;
    }

Comment: can you post your routes.xml and full controller file?

Comment: Mike. It was my mistake in controller. Thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

You must create the **ListReturns Block** `Company\Vendor\Block\Customer\ListReturns`